# Add Netbeans pre-bundled Libraries to Fresh Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have a classic `NetBeans` (8.2) Web application which uses some `Netbeans` pre-bundled libraries.

[`Project Properties` -> `Libraries` -> `Add Library`]

So I added `Jersey 2.5.1`, `JAXB 2.2.5` , `JAX-WS 2.2.6`,  `JAx-RS 2.0` libraries.

Note that every bundle contains multiple `jars`.

Now I have crated a new `Maven Web` project and I want it to have the same libraries with the first project.

So far the only way I can think of is to check every single `jar` in above libraries for `jar` version and add **one-by-one** (and by hand) dependencies to my new project.

Is there any better way to achieve the above?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

So for the `Jersey 2.5.1` I found the following dependency

(the whole bundle - no need to add every single library one by one )

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

I wonder if there are also bundles for `JAXB 2.2.5` , `JAX-WS 2.2.6` so far had  no luck finding them though.

Comment: Whoever down-voted this question - should have explained his/hers  reasons.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the support! ;-)  If it is too basic then an answer in  comments from the experts should suffice....

Comment: You are already doing the better way: you use Maven. Maven does the bundling work for you. You add the Jersey and JAX-WS RI dependencies to your pom and magically see all the dependencies that had to be manually put into those bundles be added to your project dependencies.

Comment: @GhostCat Are you sure about that (magical powers)? Cause form were I stand - it looks like you really do ;-)

Comment: @Gimby To achieve that I manually open every manifest in every jar of netbeans bundle (cause the version is not shown in jar's name) and add that jar as dependency to my maven project. We are talking about over 30-40 jars. So I thought that this could't be the right way to do this.

Comment: What web server are you using? If you configure it in NetBeans, NetBeans should take care of instructing Maven to use the libraries bundled in the web server

Comment: @perissf I am currently using tomcat (however will be using Glassfish in the future). There is a bundle called java-web-api.7.jar in the fresh project.  However I don't think that it is enough for jersey restul api implementation - which is my final goal.

Comment: Sorry, with Tomcat I can't help